# C++ Infinity While Loop with condition

Tags: c++

I am kinda new to C++, and I have encountered a problem in building a  simple c++ addition calculator. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int total = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int z = 5;

    cout << "Please enter the number you want to add" << endl;
    while(x < 5 && z != 0){
        cin >> number;

        if (!cin){
            cout << "Enter a valid number. " << "You have" << z << "tries left before this program terminate." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            z--;
        }

        else{
            total = total + number;
            x++;
        }

    }

    cout << "The total number is " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the application and then I input a non-integer, it shows "you have _ tries left" altogether. How do I make the application so that it will give the user a chance to input a something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to add

```
std::string junk;
cin >> junk;
```

just after `cin.clear()`. This will extract the junk and put it in `junk`, and just skip over it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).  I don't know how many junk characters you'll have, but you could try something like

```
cout << "Enter a valid number. " << "You have" << z << "tries left before this program terminate." << endl;
while (!cin.eof())
    cin.ignore(); 
cin.clear();
```